# Get-NetIPInterface property 'Dhcp' is 'Enabled' after setting static IP configuration with netsh

Tags: powershell, ip, windows-10, ipv4, netsh

### The Question

Set a static IP configuration with netsh:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet1" static 192.168.0.20 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Ethernet1" static 1.1.1.1 validate=no
netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="Ethernet1" addr=8.8.8.8 index=2 validate=no
```

Get the value of the `Dhcp` property with `Get-NetIPInterface`:

```
$Adapter = Get-NetAdapter 'Ethernet1'
($Adapter | Get-NetIPInterface -AddressFamily IPv4).Dhcp
```

I expect it to return `Disabled` but it returns `Enabled`.

**Why does it return `Enabled`?**

---

### Adapter Properties in Windows UI

After executing the `netsh` commands as mentioned above Windows shows these settings for the Adapter:

[image]

They look like `Dhcp` is disabled.

---

### A way to get `Get-NetIPInterface` to return `Enabled` for the property `Dhcp`

When I follow these steps:

1. Open the Adapter properties in Windows as shown above
2. Press `OK` (without changing anything)
3. Close all dialogs
4. Run `Get-NetIPInterface` as mentioned above again

Then for the property `Dhcp` it returns `Disabled` as expected.

I don't understand why, as I did not change anything.

Comment: This topic was also discussed here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/5122e251-2c7f-4c65-aeeb-c8d8ef77bc53/netsh-is-not-updating-dhcp-enable-status-to-no-when-network-cable-is-unplugged?forum=w7itpronetworking

Answer (score 0):

When using powershell to get information, why not use it to set information as well?

```
New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 192.168.0.20 -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet1' -DefaultGateway 192.168.0.1 -AddressFamily IPv4 -PrefixLength 24
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias 'Ethernet1' -serveraddresses 1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8

(Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias Wi-Fi -AddressFamily IPv4).Dhcp
Disabled
```

Why doesn't `netsh` set the same dhcp setting? I can't be sure, but it probably has something to do with `netsh` making changes to the older `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class, while powershell's `NetTCPIP` module checks the newer `MSFT_NetIPInterface`. It might be that powershell checks some cached version and gives you the old value. Try comparing the output of these two commands?

```
Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select DHCPEnabled,Description
Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root/StandardCimv2 -ClassName MSFT_NetIPInterface | Select Dhcp,InterfaceAlias
```

Comment: Both commands give the same output about DHCP as `Get-NetIPInterface`. If I set static IP settings with the ui the commands return that DHCP is `disabled` (as expected). If I set static IP settings with `netsh` the commands return that DHCP is still `enabled` (but I expect DHCP to be `disabled`).

Comment: @Silv If you set a static IP with powershell instead of `netsh`,  does powershell still return that DHCP is enabled? And for your comment above, are you changing DHCP setttings while the interface is down/disconnected?

Comment: I did not try setting IP settings with PowerShell. Yes I changed DHCP settings while the interface is disconnected and I read that it should work if the interface is connected, but it must be disconnected in my case.